# Div not moving up

Tags: css, html

Basically I am about to finish my first real index.html but a stubborn mistake is preventing me from doing so. The "Twitter" div isn't positioning itself just right of the  24 hour one, it is instead getting stuck in the by the middle. Namely this:

HTML

```
<div id="divFooter">
    <div id="row1">
         <h4 id="title4">24 HOUR CUSTOMER SERVICE</h4>

        <div id="contactos">
            <img src="imgs/icon-phone.png" id="custumerServiceImg">
            <p>512-943-1069</p>
            <p>512-943-1068</p>
        </div>
        <div id="contactos" class="color">
            <img src="imgs/icon-email.png" id="custumerServiceImg">
            <p><a href="#">info@WTPcom</a>

            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="contactos">
            <img src="imgs/icon-address.png" id="custumerServiceImg">
            <p>1341 Oakmound Drive</p>
            <p>Chicago, IL 60609</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tweets" class="color">
         <h4 id="title4">RECENT TWEETS</h4>

        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p><a href="#">- 1 day ago</a>

        </p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        <p>
            <p><a href="#">- 2 days ago</a>

            </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#divFooter {
    background: url("../imgs/bg-footer.jpg");
    position: relative;
    margin: 400px 0 0 0;
    height: 291px;
    width: 956px;
}
#custumerServiceImg {
    float: left;
}
#row1 {
    width: 318px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
#row1 p {
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    color: #404040;
    font-family:'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#row1 img {
    margin: 0px 0 10px 0;
}
#contactos {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
#title4 {
    color: #404040;
    font-family:'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#tweets {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 0 500px 250px;
    width: 318px;
}
```

Any help and indications of how not to fail like this again will be deeply appreciated
Best Wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `float:left` to your `#row1`

```
#row1{
  float:left;
width: 318px;
padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

See Working [**Lab Demo**](http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab/2Sp7qHnMMZOVZwrYrmMRvypyRCajQX~n)

Comment: Thanks a lot to think it was something so obvious!

Comment: I didn´t know sorry, I will do it now.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this css with yours

```
#tweets{ position: absolute; width: 318px; top:0; left:330px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/